# Compact sets in $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Prove that a compact set $K$ in $\mathbb R$ is of the form $[a,b]$ or $[a,b]$ - $X$ where $X$ is countable union of disjoint open sets such that the endpoints are in K.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT:** Compact sets are closed and bounded in $\Bbb R$. Open sets can be written as a disjoint countable union of open intervals.

Comment: Does this mean compact sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are countable unions of intervals $[a,b]$?

Comment: Think about your question for a moment. You don't need me to answer it.

Comment: Maybe you could tell me if my thinking is correct? Take a compact set of the form $K = [a,b] \setminus \bigcup_j I_j$ where $\{I_j\}$ is a countable collection of disjoint open intervals. This seems like we are just chopping out open intervals form inside $[a,b]$. If the collection is finite, it seems obvious we get a union of closed intervals. I am wondering if I am missing something when the collection is countably infinite. The endpoints of the intervals we cut out must have a limit point in $[a,b]$.

Comment: @RitterSport: Yes, you are missing something obvious. Take the Cantor set, which is probably what you had in mind. Every point in the Cantor set is a limit of endpoints of the open intervals removed; but it is not necessary *an* endpoint of any of them. This is what separates a regular open set from an arbitrary open set. And the complement of the Cantor set is **not** a regular open set.

Comment: Thanks very much. I had never seen the notion of regular open set. I admit I should have thought about the Cantor set, though.